# Solving coupled PDEs with self-consistency condition

Tags: finite-element, computational-physics, nonlinear-equations, fenics

I am figuring out how to attack a problem (the Usadel equations of superconductivity) in which I need to solve a set of nonlinear PDEs for the fields $\{G_i (r)\}$
$$ U(G_i(r), \nabla G_i(r), \Delta(r) ) = 0\,, $$
together with a (nonlinear, algebraic) self-consistency condition
$$V({G_i (r)}, \Delta(r) ) = 0\,.$$

The usual way to solve this problem in the literature is to discretize the PDEs using finite differences and with a segregated approach: solving the PDEs given $\Delta(r)$ for the fields $G_i(r)$, then computing the self-consistent field $\Delta$ solving the non-linear equation, then use the updated $\Delta(r)$ for a new iteration of PDEs and so on until convergence.

I was wondering about the feasibility of using a finite element approach and maybe even solving the system of equations as a fully-coupled problem. In particular, I would like to use FEniCS. Is it doable? Do you know any example of a similar computational problem I can study?

I guess coding the solver for the PDEs would be fairly simple and it would probably be easy to find some examples. What worries me is the self-consistency condition as it's a non-linear algebraic equation and I have not a clear idea on how to write it down in a finite-element environment.

When I tried something similar (for a different problem) in Comsol I found some convergence issues as the lack of gradient terms would cause strong spatial variations of the fields.

---

Edit:

The specific form of Usadel equations depends on the system studied and approximation used, however an example of the PDEs (taken from the supplementary material of https://journals.aps.org/prb/supplemental/10.1103/PhysRevB.103.L020504) is the following:
$$
\begin{cases}
(D \nabla^2 - 2 \omega_n) f^s_n(r) = - 2 \pi \Delta(r) + 2 i \vec{h}(r)\cdot\vec{f}^t_n(r) \\
(D \nabla^2 - 2 \omega_n) \vec{f}^t_n(r) =  2 i \vec{h}(r) f^s_n(r) \\
\end{cases}
$$

while the self-consistency equation may look like
$$
-\Delta(r)\ln(\tau) = 2 \tau \sum_{n=0}^{n_{cutoff}} \Big(\frac{\Delta(r)}{2 \omega_n}-f^s_n(r)\Big)
$$
In this case, $f^{s,t}_n(r)$ are the unknown fields in the PDEs while $\Delta(r)$ is the self-consistent field (unknown as well), while $\tau$ and $\vec{h}$ are the external parameters. In the numerical implementation, $n$ are integer numbers comprised between 0 and a cutoff which can be placed around a hundred. The domain is a simple rectangle.

Comment: Can you spell out how the equations actually look like?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I've added an example of the equations. However, they can vary a lot depending on the specific approximation of the system modeled.

Comment: I can't see the images you linked in. Can you update the source, or maybe just include the equations as actual (latex-style) formulas?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I wrote them in Latex now.

Comment: In these equations, what are the unknown functions? $f_n^s$ and $f_n^t$, or also $\Delta$?

Comment: The unknown functions are $\{f_n^s\}$, $\{\vec{f}_n^t\}$ and $\Delta$. It is a coupled problem consisting of a pair of PDEs for each $n$ plus one algebraic self-consistentcy equation. Usually, people see them as separate problems, first they solve the PDEs for the $f$ functions for a given $\Delta$ field, then $\Delta$ is calculated from the self-consistency equation and put back in the PDEs and so on (the segregated approach).

Comment: There is https://fenicsproject.org/community/ and https://fenicsproject.discourse.group/ for reference, if you want to explicitly ask this to the FEniCS community

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I would look at how people solve the "black oil" or "oil/water/gas" equations. They have a similar structure.

Comment: Why do you say they are similar? If black oil equations are the ones I can find on Wikipedia they seem just a set of PDEs without something like the self-consistency condition I need.

Comment: Once you discretize your PDEs by your favorite method (FD,FV,FEM,spectral) they become [linear or nonlinear] algebraic equations, same as your algebraic constraint equation. So with the constraint or without it, it all boils down to solving a system of linear or nonlinear algebraic (or perhaps transcendental) equations.